# Organize JSON data in columns with PYTHON

Tags: python, json, pandas, datatable

I need to read a JSON with PYTHON and display the data from the same JSON, in a table, organized according to my OUTPUT >>>> [EXPECTED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12sI0.jpg)

I'm creating a table and giving it titles, but I can't print beyond a correct line with the data, I want to make it dynamic, that is, while "DS" has data I want to print it, and if any item in the same line doesn't have just complete with "NONE" [MY OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73GWA.png)

As I mentioned above, I was trying to give the table titles and fill each column with its respective data, but I am not getting all the data, only 1 line of data

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Carregar os dados do JSON
with open("data.json", "r") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# Extrair o dicionário "ValueDicts"
value_dicts = data["results"][0]["result"]["data"]["dsr"]["DS"][0]["ValueDicts"]

# Extrair os valores iniciais
initial_values = [
    value_dicts["D0"][0], "DS", value_dicts["D1"][0], value_dicts["D2"][0],
    value_dicts["D3"][0], value_dicts["D4"][0], value_dicts["D5"][0],
    value_dicts["D6"][0], value_dicts["D7"][0], value_dicts["D8"][0],
    value_dicts["D9"][0], value_dicts["D10"][0], value_dicts["D11"][0],
    value_dicts["D12"][0], value_dicts["D13"][0]
]

# Criar um DataFrame vazio com as colunas especificadas
colunas = ["G" + str(i) for i in range(15)]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=colunas)

# Preencher a primeira linha com os títulos dos dados
titles = [
    "NOM_MES_ABREV", "DS", "COD_OPERACAO", "COD_INSTALACAO_ORIG", "SIG_UF_ORIG",
    "SIG_REGIAO_ORIG", "RAZAO_SOCIAL_DEST", "SIG_UF_DEST", "SIG_REGIAO_DEST",
    "QUALIF_DEST", "TIPO_EXTRACAO", "C_UF", "C_REGIAO", "C2_LOCALIZAÇÃO", "C_UF_Restrito"
]
df.loc[0] = titles

# Preencher a segunda linha com os valores iniciais
df.loc[1] = initial_values

# Preencher as linhas restantes com os valores das listas
num_rows = max(len(value) for value in value_dicts.values())
for row_num in range(2, num_rows + 2):  # Começa da terceira linha
    new_row = []
    for key in df.columns:
        if key in value_dicts:
            if row_num - 2 < len(value_dicts[key]):
                new_row.append(value_dicts[key][row_num - 2])
            else:
                new_row.append(None)
        else:
            new_row.append('')
    df.loc[row_num] = new_row

# Visualizar o DataFrame resultante
print(df)
```

**And This is My JSON**

```
{
  "jobIds": [
     "78321e6f-2030-4c7c-a6d3-ee3363e2b8fe"
  ],
  "results": [
     {
        "jobId": "78321e6f-2030-4c7c-a6d3-ee3363e2b8fe",
        "result": {
           "data": {
              "timestamp": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.589Z",
              "rootActivityId": "5f99b36b-13c6-4e6e-9625-90a01455c0f2",
              "descriptor": {
                 "Select": [
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G0",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "DM_TEMPO",
                                "Property": "NOM_MES_ABREV"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G0",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "DM_TEMPO.NOM_MES_ABREV"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G1",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "QTD_PRODUTO"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G1",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "Sum((Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.QTD_PRODUTO)"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G2",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "COD_OPERACAO"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G2",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.COD_OPERACAO"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G3",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "COD_INSTALACAO_ORIG"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G3",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.COD_INSTALACAO_ORIG"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G4",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "SIG_UF_ORIG"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G4",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.SIG_UF_ORIG"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G5",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "SIG_REGIAO_ORIG"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G5",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.SIG_REGIAO_ORIG"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G6",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "RAZAO_SOCIAL_DEST"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G6",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.RAZAO_SOCIAL_DEST"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G7",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "SIG_UF_DEST"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G7",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.SIG_UF_DEST"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G8",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "SIG_REGIAO_DEST"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G8",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.SIG_REGIAO_DEST"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G9",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "QUALIF_DEST"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G9",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.QUALIF_DEST"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G10",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "TIPO_EXTRACAO"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G10",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.TIPO_EXTRACAO"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G11",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "C_UF"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G11",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.C_UF"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G12",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "C_REGIAO"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G12",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.C_REGIAO"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G13",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "C2_LOCALIZAÇÃO"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G13",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.C2_LOCALIZAÇÃO"
                    },
                    {
                       "Kind": 1,
                       "Depth": 0,
                       "Value": "G14",
                       "GroupKeys": [
                          {
                             "Source": {
                                "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                "Property": "C_UF_Restrito"
                             },
                             "Calc": "G14",
                             "IsSameAsSelect": true
                          }
                       ],
                       "Name": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO.C_UF_Restrito"
                    }
                 ],
                 "Expressions": {
                    "Primary": {
                       "Groupings": [
                          {
                             "Keys": [
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "DM_TEMPO",
                                      "Property": "NOM_MES_ABREV"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 0
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "QTD_PRODUTO"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 1
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "COD_OPERACAO"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 2
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "COD_INSTALACAO_ORIG"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 3
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "SIG_UF_ORIG"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 4
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "SIG_REGIAO_ORIG"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 5
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "RAZAO_SOCIAL_DEST"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 6
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "SIG_UF_DEST"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 7
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "SIG_REGIAO_DEST"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 8
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "QUALIF_DEST"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 9
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "TIPO_EXTRACAO"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 10
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "C_UF"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 11
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "C_REGIAO"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 12
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "C2_LOCALIZAÇÃO"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 13
                                },
                                {
                                   "Source": {
                                      "Entity": "(Movimento) - FT_SDL_MOVIMENTO",
                                      "Property": "C_UF_Restrito"
                                   },
                                   "Select": 14
                                }
                             ],
                             "Member": "DM0"
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 },
                 "Limits": {
                    "Primary": {
                       "Id": "L0",
                       "Top": {
                          "Count": 1000
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 "Version": 2
              },
              "metrics": {
                 "Version": "1.0.0",
                 "Events": [
                    {
                       "Id": "ca5e94f5-318e-4de3-8a88-e94cc1105181",
                       "Name": "Execute Semantic Query",
                       "Component": "DSE",
                       "Start": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.5899491Z",
                       "End": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.6524475Z"
                    },
                    {
                       "Id": "fb1cac7d-cf39-44b2-ac95-8db41fdcb6c4",
                       "ParentId": "ca5e94f5-318e-4de3-8a88-e94cc1105181",
                       "Name": "Execute DAX Query",
                       "Component": "DSE",
                       "Start": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.5899491Z",
                       "End": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.6524475Z",
                       "Metrics": {
                          "RowCount": 4
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "Id": "08875535-8F1B-41A6-9820-8DB70C25747B",
                       "ParentId": "fb1cac7d-cf39-44b2-ac95-8db41fdcb6c4",
                       "Name": "Execute Query",
                       "Component": "AS",
                       "Start": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.637Z",
                       "End": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.647Z"
                    },
                    {
                       "Id": "85BA220D-C873-4C33-BD39-258AF2B07039",
                       "ParentId": "08875535-8F1B-41A6-9820-8DB70C25747B",
                       "Name": "Serialize Rowset",
                       "Component": "AS",
                       "Start": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.647Z",
                       "End": "2023-08-16T19:49:00.647Z"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              "fromCache": false,
              "dsr": {
                 "Version": 2,
                 "MinorVersion": 1,
                 "DS": [
                    {
                       "N": "DS0",
                       "PH": [
                          {
                             "DM0": [
                                {
                                   "S": [
                                      {
                                         "N": "G0",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D0"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G1",
                                         "T": 3
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G2",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D1"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G3",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D2"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G4",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D3"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G5",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D4"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G6",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D5"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G7",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D6"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G8",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D7"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G9",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D8"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G10",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D9"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G11",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D10"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G12",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D11"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G13",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D12"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "N": "G14",
                                         "T": 1,
                                         "DN": "D13"
                                      }
                                   ],
                                   "C": [
                                      0,
                                      "0.0018000000000000002",
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      0
                                   ]
                                },
                                {
                                   "C": [
                                      "0.0096499999999999989",
                                      1,
                                      1,
                                      1,
                                      1,
                                      1
                                   ],
                                   "R": 30561
                                },
                                {
                                   "C": [
                                      0.02252,
                                      2,
                                      2,
                                      2
                                   ],
                                   "R": 30581
                                },
                                {
                                   "C": [
                                      0.02864,
                                      2,
                                      1,
                                      3,
                                      3
                                   ],
                                   "R": 30521
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                       ],
                       "IC": true,
                       "HAD": true,
                       "ValueDicts": {
                          "D0": [
                             "Jan"
                          ],
                          "D1": [
                             "26",
                             "15",
                             "14"
                          ],
                          "D2": [
                             "1038329",
                             "1033638",
                             "1232257"
                          ],
                          "D3": [
                             "TO",
                             "AM"
                          ],
                          "D4": [
                             "N"
                          ],
                          "D5": [
                             "NÃO INFORMADO",
                             "CONSORCIO SANCHES TRIPOLONI-COEMA-PLANNUS"
                          ],
                          "D6": [
                             "TO",
                             "AM",
                             "RO",
                             "RR"
                          ],
                          "D7": [
                             "N"
                          ],
                          "D8": [
                             "CONSUMIDOR FINAL"
                          ],
                          "D9": [
                             "Dist"
                          ],
                          "D10": [
                             "TO",
                             "AM",
                             "RO",
                             "RR"
                          ],
                          "D11": [
                             "N"
                          ],
                          "D12": [
                             "NÃO INFORMADO"
                          ],
                          "D13": [
                             "Os dados por UF não estão disponíveis para este ano."
                          ]
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In your expected output, for data `D2` you extend `[ "1038329", "1033638", "1232257" ]` to 4 values as `[ "1038329", "1033638", "1232257", "1232257" ]` (i.e. copy the 3rd value to the 4th) but for `D5` you extend `[ "NÃO INFORMADO", "CONSORCIO SANCHES TRIPOLONI-COEMA-PLANNUS" ]` as `[ "NÃO INFORMADO",  "NÃO INFORMADO",  "NÃO INFORMADO", "CONSORCIO SANCHES TRIPOLONI-COEMA-PLANNUS" ]` (i.e. copy the 1st value to the 2nd and 3rd). How do you decide which way to extend the data?

Comment: How i do this on code?